# don;t know why code is not working oracle live sql ,getting errors like ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE 
 v_annual_salary NUMBER;
 
 BEGIN
   SELECT SAL * 12 INTO v_annual_salary
   FROM EMP,DEPT
   WHERE EMPNO = 7722;
   
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Annual Salary of 7722 is ' || TO_CHAR(v_annual_salary));
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `DEPT` table contains a single row, this query will return `TOO_MANY_ROWS`. Why do you cross-join `EMP` and `DEPT`? Should have been just

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_annual_salary number;
  3  begin
  4    select sal * 12
  5      into v_annual_salary
  6      from emp
  7      where empno = 7934;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Annual salary of 7934 is ' || to_char(v_annual_salary));
 10  end;
 11  /
Annual salary of 7934 is 15600

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

(My `EMP` table doesn't have employee whose `EMPNO = 7722` so I used `7934`).